# dynamically generate folder and csv file inside with php code

Tags: file, csv, download, generate

I want to generate a csv file inside dynamically generated folder and push record in csv file row wise using php function

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
```

function to generate directory using php and create a csv file inside folder and write array record in csv fil.